# Is there a way to create bar plot of the frequency of "Yes" "No" values across multiple variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data:
[image: My data]

I have a data set containing presence of various chemicals across multiple waterbodies. I want to create a barplot of the frequency of "Yes" values across multiple variables/columns.

I've tried various attempts using base r and `ggplot2`, the problem I am consistently running into is that the functions want the sub variable id or just a singular variable and I am looking to select the range of chem1 through chem5 to display.

```r
ggplot(MyData, aes(x=3:7, y="Yes")) + geom_bar()
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I know this does not work but I wanted to attach to delineate my goal in r. The 3:7 is the range of columns I want plotted.

I am new to R and sifted through similar questions and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Please consider adding data to your questions rather than posting an image. You can do that using `dput(df)`.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please don't post pictures of data; we cannot copy/paste those values in R for testing. The main problem seems to be your data is not in a "tidy" format that `ggplot` expected it to be. Different bars should correspond to different rows, not columns. `pivot_longer` can help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For plotting with `ggplot2`, the data should be in a long format. Once it is in long format, then we can just keep the `Yes` values, and use `count` with `geom_bar`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  filter(value == "Yes") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(chem1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"), chem2 = c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```